# How to create a installer for .net core application created on windows but to be deployed on Mac OS x

Tags: .net, macos, .net-core, installation, setup-deployment

We are developing a .net core web api using visual studio 2017 on windows. This .net core web api needs to be deployed on apache server on Mac OS x.
I was able to publish the binaries for runtime identifier osx-x64 and was also able to host it on apache on Mac by copying the "publish" folder manually over to the mac machine. All the apache .conf file and the .plist file were copied manually.

Now the question is how to create a installer for Mac that will install this .net core web api on the Mac machine and automate the hosting process?

Thanks

Comment: You can try https://wannabeegeek.com/2016/08/06/running-your-first-asp-net-core-web-api-on-mac/ might be it will help you

Comment: A Web API project for macOS? It sounds really weird. Common approaches for macOS apps are, Mac App Store or .dmg for GUI apps, package manager such as Homebrew for command line tools. You can also ship .zip if the program is self contained. So this is too broad a question to discuss.